# Android studio gradle flavor dimensions build varients not working correctly

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I have two dimensions of an app, call then green and blue. There will only be these two dimensions but an unlimited number of product flavors. This is the way I'm setting it up in gradle

```
flavorDimensions "green", "blue"

productFlavors {

    one {
        applicationId "com.app.green.one"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0.1";
        flavorDimension = "green"
    }
    two {
        applicationId "com.app.blue.two"
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.0.1";
        flavorDimension = "blue"
    }
}
```

But then after i sync gradle, in the build variants tab all I see is oneTwoDebug and oneTwoRelease, where I should see  greenOneDebug greenOneRelease, blueTwoDebug, blueTwoRelease

In theory I want to extend it to be something like this

```
one {
    applicationId "com.app.green.one"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0.1";
    flavorDimension = "green"
}
two {
    applicationId "com.app.blue.two"
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.0.1";
    flavorDimension = "blue"
}
three {
    applicationId "com.app.green.three"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0.1";
    flavorDimension = "green"
}
four {
    applicationId "com.app.blue.four"
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.0.1";
    flavorDimension = "blue"
}
```

In this case dimensions represent the "type" of app, and then the flavors are more for organizations which can be added.

**EDIT I had the wrong set up for gradle as pointed out here is a more accurate depiction of what I have

```
flavorDimensions "type", "organization"

productFlavors {

    blue {
        applicationId "com.app.blue"
        flavorDimension = "type"
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.0.1";
    }
    red {
        applicationId "com.app.red"
        flavorDimension = "type"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0.1";
    }

    company1 {
        flavorDimension = "organization"
    }
    company2 {
        flavorDimension = "organization"
    }
}
```

So far this works, So I can create java source directories for toggling types, but what if I want organization specific config files, do I create java source dirs for each organization as well?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the concept of flavorDimension.

A flavorDimension is something like a *flavor category* and every combination of a flavor from each dimension will produce a variant.

In your case, you must define one flavorDimension named "type" and another dimension named "organization". 
It will produce, for each flavor in the dimension "organization" all possible "type" (or the dual formulation : for each "type" it will produce a variant for each organization).

The flavor dimensions define the *cartesian product* that will be used to produce variants.

---

**EDIT** : I'll try to illustrate with pseudo-gradle code:

Let's define some "type" : bronze, silver and gold

Let's define some organizations : customerA, customerB, customerC

All those are *productFlavors*, but they belong to 2 different dimensions:

```
flavorDimensions("type_line", "organization")
productFlavors {

    gold {
        ...
        dimension = "type_line"
    }
    silver {
        ...
        dimension = "type_line"
    }
    bronze {
         ...
        dimension = "type_line"
    }

     customerA {
        ...
        dimension = "organization"
    }
    customerB {
        ...
        dimension = "organization"
    }
    customerC {
         ...
        dimension = "organization"
    }

}
```

This config will produce 18 (3*3*2) variants (if you have the 2 standard build types : debug and release) :

gold-customerA-debug ; gold-customerA-release ; gold-customerB-debug ; gold-customerB-release ; gold-customerC-debug ; gold-customerC-release ;

silver-customerA-debug ; silver-customerA-release ; silver-customerB-debug ; silver-customerB-release ; silver-customerC-debug ; silver-customerC-release ;

... (the same for bronze)

Note that the name of the dimension is totally arbitrary and have no impact on variant names.

Flavor dimensions are very powerful, but if you use too much of them : it results in an exponential explosion of the number of variants (a post build clean-up task may be useful to delete useless or non-sense variant)

Comment: that makes a little more sense but each product flavor needs to define a flavorDimension, so if each flavor is a combination of both how does that work

Comment: I guess really what im trying to do is sub flavor flavors in a sense

Comment: Thanks for the example! I just figured out how it worked after your previous comment, this makes a lot more sense, ONE last question if you can, if I want a config file for the organizations as well, does each organization need its own java source directory? or does the organization config have to be placed within the "type" config? does that make sense

Comment: You can create additional java/ , res/ or assets/ directory for each product flavor under /src/flavorName/java (resp. src/flavorName/res and src/flavorName/assets) and each variant will include the sources under src/main/ + the sources under src/flavorName/  (I don't understand what you mean by "placed within the type config")

Comment: yeah I was over thinking it, I did that as well, thanks for your help

Comment: @ben75 instead of a "clean-up task", use the [variantFilter](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#filter-variants) block to reduce the number of variants and exclude useless combinations