# What is the use of flavorDimensions in builld.gradle (AndroidStudio)?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-flavors, android-flavordimension

I opened one project in `build.gradle` was also something unfamiliar to me:

```
flavorDimensions "release", "default"

productFlavors {

        main {
            applicationId "com.xxxx.xxxx"
            dimension "default"
        }
        underground {
            applicationId "com.xxxx.xxx"
            dimension "default"
        }
        google {
            dimension "release"
        }
        amazon {
            dimension "release"
        }
}
```

What is the use of this?

Comment: you can check answer for above on this link . 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/30855016/4919210

Comment: I dont know if is duplicate or not but I would like to know why you need this (favorDimensions)?

Comment: if you are aware of build flavours which we use to create builds/apk of different url and configuration. we use to declare them previously in build.gradle.  But now the process of declaration is been changed and properties is been updated for them.

Comment: Does that mean if I want to export different apk for example  google play and amazon?

Comment: Kind of , manly this is related to if you want different variant of same application to upload on play store or amazon

Comment: aha.... so can you make one apk which have different ("settings") for both  amazon and play store?